# C++ build - namespace and no member

Tags: c++, build, intel

I have this code:

MyMathUtils.h

```
#ifndef MY_MATH_UTILS_H
#define MY_MATH_UTILS_H


#include "./Ray.h"
#include "./RayTriangleResult .h"
#include "./Triangle.h"

namespace MyMath 
{


    class MyMathUtils 
    {
        public: 
           static bool RayTriangleIntersection(const MyMath::Ray & ray, const MyMath::Triangle & t, MyMath::RayTriangleResult * out);
        //other code
    };
}
#endif
```

and 
Triangle.h

```
#ifndef MY_TRIANGLE_H
#define MY_TRIANGLE_H

namespace MyMath
{
    struct Triangle
    {
       //code
    };
}
#endif
```

But during compile, I have got this error:

> D:\C++\C++\MyMath\header./MyMathUtils.h(71): error : namespace
>   "MyMath" has no member "Triangle" 
>   static bool
>   RayTriangleIntersection(const MyMath::Ray & ray, const
>   MyMath::Triangle & t, MyMath::RayTriangleResult * out);

I am using Intel C++ 15.0 compiler

Comment: You don't include any header files in `Triangle.h`, that could cause a circular inclusion dependency with `MyMathUtils.h`? That error message is complete? You didn't misspell `Triangle` in your actual code?

Comment: You didn't by mistake copy `MY_TRIANGLE_H` inclusion guard into one of the other two header files, right?

Comment: I checked, there is no MY_TRIANGLE_H elsewhere. Also, no spelling error. I have also tried to add forward declacation to MyMathUtils for Triangle, but same error